# Running Standard ML on Windows

Tags: windows, sml, smlnj, ml, polyml

I have been looking for some good documentation on how to get Standard ML running on windows.  Does anyone have a good guide on this?

I have tried compiling sml/nj in cygwin, using this guide: http://www.smlnj.org/install/index.html

```
$ config/install.sh
config/install.sh: Using shell /bin/sh.
config/install.sh: SML root is /usr/local/sml.
config/install.sh: Installation directory is /usr/local/sml.
config/install.sh: Installing version 110.74.
config/install.sh: URL of source archive is http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.74/.
config/install.sh: Script /usr/local/sml/bin/.arch-n-opsys reports ARCH=x86; OPSYS=win32; HEAP_SUFFIX=x86-win32.
/usr/local/sml/config/unpack: The run-time tree already exists.
config/install.sh: Compiling the run-time system.
(nmake /Fmakefile.win32 MAKE="nmake /Fmakefile.win32" RUNTIME="run.x86-win32.exe" VERSION="v-x86-win32" CC="cl" CFLAGS="/Zi" CPP="cl /E /EP" TARGET=X86 DEFS="  /DHOST_X86 /DTARGET_X86 /DOPSYS_WIN32 /DVREGS /DINDIRECT_CFUNC /DDLOPEN" XOBJS="" XLIBS="" LD_LIBS="" XCLIBS="" run.x86-win32.exe)
make: -c: Command not found
mk.x86-win32:26: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
config/install.sh: !!! Run-time system build failed for some reason.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran into the same problem (and ultimately ended up using a the Windows msi). I dug into the code, and it seems that the install script doesn't recognize the information Cygwin provides about the OS; even after adding in information, it still didn't work for me because some of the code is written in 32-bit assembly, while the compiler uses 64-bit C libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Moscow ML](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosml.html) (MosML) works out of the box on Windows (No need for cygwin). You can either download a zip-file or a self-extracting installer.

The website also contains a fairly good documentation (good for some of the MosML specific parts) and links to other good references.

Regarding your issue, the guide you refer to doesn't mention compiling sml/nj on windows. Just by using cygwin doesn't make it "linux" (cygwin has quite some quirks).
The source contains some [notes](http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.73/NOTES/CYGWININSTALL) on how to install (and compile) on cygwin. Note if you are using an older version of sml/nj, then it is not necessarily compatible with cygwin.

On a side note. There exists a msi installer for windows, why not use that?

Comment: the msi looks like the way to go.  (though the windows cmd prompt is a little horrible)

Answer (score 2):

It has become a running gag in the long history of Standard ML that its best implementation is hardly known: [Poly/ML](http://www.polyml.org/).

The [releases](https://github.com/polyml/polyml/releases) at Github also include MSIs for Windows.

Comment: When I use that (5.7 x64) .msi all I get is a shabby PolyML.exe which appears to be a windows repl application or something. Where is the compiler and all the rest?

Comment: FYI out of the box Poly/ML doesn't seem to support `use` statements (i.e. module imports) for source files in a different directory than the current one (eg `use "../util.sml;"`), whereas SML/NJ does. Poly doesn't perform the `chdir` under the hood required for the paths to make sense. Huge barrier to entry if you're just using SML for educational/exploratory purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick and dirty implementation you might want to try [Cambridge ML](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/FoundsCS/usingml.html). We use it for teaching undergraduates ML here in Cambridge. Not the best option for large scale development but adequate for teaching the basics of the language.